# Ruby strptime method error

Tags: ruby

So I am working through a tutorial building an event manager program and I'm a bit stuck. I want to build a method that will take registration data from a .csv file and then extract the hour times when people registered. However I'm having trouble getting it to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
def reg_hour(regtime)
    regtime = DateTime.new
    DateTime.strptime(regtime, "%H")

end
```

When I run the code though I get this error:

```
 `block in _strptime_i': undefined method `sub!' for #<DateTime: -4712-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 (-1/2,0,2299161)> (NoMethodError)
```

I am quite confused and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the link to the tutorial if anyone is interested. 
http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/eventmanager.html

Comment: remove `regtime = DateTime.new` and change the next line by `DateTime.strptime(regtime, "%H")`

Comment: Thanks for the help @varnie. Thing is now I'm getting a wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're doing with the DateTime.new and overriding the regtime variable (I'm new to ruby myself). If the regtime is coming out of a csv file, it's probably coming out as a string. Perhaps you could use a regular expression as long as the regdate format is consistent.

If regdate is: "11/12/08 10:47"

Then using:

```
regdate.scan(/\s\d+:/)
```

Would return [" 10:"]. Perhaps then you could store that in a array variable and clean it up by removing white space and the colon. There's probably a more elegant solution, but that's my newbie brute force way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure I fully understand your intentions, but here it is rewritten:

```
require 'time'

def reg_hour(regtime)
    DateTime.strptime(regtime, "%H")
end

d = reg_hour("21/03/2011 14:39:11.642")
puts d.year
```

Is this something you're trying to do?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have the method pull information from the .csv file and then take the hour out of that info. Here's my latest attempt:

def reg_hour(regtime)
 regtime.strptime(regtime, "%H")
end

from the error message I'm getting it looks like it's pulling the info out but it doesn't seem to know what to do with the strptime method. Here's the error:

`reg_hour': undefined method `strptime' for "11/12/08 10:47":String (NoMethodError)

Any ideas @varnie? I've also required 'date' and 'time' at the top.